# RecyclerView lags on scrolling

Tags: java, performance, android, gui

I'm having an issue where when the recyclerview has a big amount of items (say 2000) the scrolling is really laggy.

Here's the Fragment code:

```
package jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.pluscubed.recyclerfastscroll.RecyclerFastScroller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.R;
import jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.adapters.IconsAdapter;
import jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.utilities.Preferences;
import jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.adapters.AlphaInAnimationAdapter;
import jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.adapters.ScaleInAnimationAdapter;

public class IconsFragment extends Fragment {

    private IconsAdapter mAdapter;
    private Preferences mPrefs;
    private ArrayList<String> iconsNames, filteredIconsList;
    private ArrayList<Integer> iconsInts, filteredIconsInts;
    private ViewGroup layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mPrefs = new Preferences(getActivity());

        if (layout != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) layout.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(layout);
            }
        }
        try {
            layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.icons_grid, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {

        }

        RecyclerFastScroller fastScroller =
                (RecyclerFastScroller) layout.findViewById(R.id.rvFastScroller);
        fastScroller.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        RecyclerView iconsGrid = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.iconsGrid);
        iconsGrid.setHasFixedSize(true);
        iconsGrid.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                getResources().getInteger(R.integer.icon_grid_width)));

        mAdapter = new IconsAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            iconsNames = getArguments().getStringArrayList("iconsNamesList");
            iconsInts = getArguments().getIntegerArrayList("iconsArray");
            mAdapter.setIcons(iconsNames, iconsInts);
        }

        iconsGrid.setAdapter(mPrefs.getAnimationsEnabled() ? animAdapter(mAdapter) : mAdapter);
        fastScroller.setRecyclerView(iconsGrid);
        fastScroller.setHideDelay(500);
        fastScroller.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return layout;
    }

    public static IconsFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> iconsNames, ArrayList<Integer> iconsArray) {
        IconsFragment fragment = new IconsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArrayList("iconsNamesList", iconsNames);
        args.putIntegerArrayList("iconsArray", iconsArray);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void performSearch(String query) {
        filter(query, mAdapter);
    }

    private synchronized void filter(CharSequence s, IconsAdapter adapter) {
        if (s == null || s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            if (filteredIconsList != null) {
                filteredIconsList = null;
            }
            if (filteredIconsInts != null) {
                filteredIconsList = null;
            }
            adapter.clearIconsList();
            adapter.setIcons(iconsNames, iconsInts);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            if (filteredIconsList != null) {
                filteredIconsList.clear();
            }
            if (filteredIconsInts != null) {
                filteredIconsList = null;
            }
            filteredIconsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            filteredIconsInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < iconsNames.size(); i++) {
                String name = iconsNames.get(i);
                if (name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .startsWith(s.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) {
                    filteredIconsList.add(iconsNames.get(i));
                    filteredIconsInts.add(iconsInts.get(i));
                }
            }
            adapter.clearIconsList();
            adapter.setIcons(filteredIconsList, filteredIconsInts);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private ScaleInAnimationAdapter animAdapter(IconsAdapter iconsAdapter) {
        AlphaInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(iconsAdapter);
        ScaleInAnimationAdapter scaleAdapter = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(alphaAdapter);
        scaleAdapter.setFirstOnly(true);
        return scaleAdapter;
    }

}
```

And RecyclerView adapter:

```
package jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.R;
import jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.utilities.Util;

public class IconsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IconsAdapter.IconsHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final Context context;
    final Resources r;
    final String p;
    private ArrayList<String> iconsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> iconsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public IconsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> iconsList, ArrayList<Integer> iconsArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.iconsList = iconsList;
        this.iconsArray = iconsArray;
        r = context.getResources();
        p = context.getPackageName();
    }

    public void setIcons(ArrayList<String> iconsList, ArrayList<Integer> iconsArray) {
        this.iconsList.addAll(iconsList);
        this.iconsArray.addAll(iconsArray);
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, iconsList.size() - 1);
    }

    public void clearIconsList() {
        this.iconsList.clear();
        this.iconsArray.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public IconsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new IconsHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_icon, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(IconsHolder holder, int position) {
        if (iconsArray.size() > 0) {
            holder.icon.setImageResource(iconsArray.get(position));
        }
        holder.view.setTag(position);
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(this);
        setAnimation(holder.icon, position);
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            viewToAnimate.setHasTransientState(true);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return iconsList == null ? 0 : iconsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        int resId = iconsArray.get(position);
        String name = iconsList.get(position).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                .customView(R.layout.dialog_icon, false)
                .title(Util.makeTextReadable(name))
                .positiveText(R.string.close)
                .show();

        if (dialog.getCustomView() != null) {
            ImageView dialogIcon = (ImageView) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.dialogicon);
            dialogIcon.setImageResource(resId);
        }
    }

    class IconsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final View view;
        final ImageView icon;

        IconsHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = v;
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_img);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please declare your [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34365550/1157100).

Answer (score 2):

```
private synchronized void filter(CharSequence s, IconsAdapter adapter) {
    if (s == null || s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        if (filteredIconsList != null) {
            filteredIconsList = null;
        }
        if (filteredIconsInts != null) {
            filteredIconsList = null;
        }
        ...
```

This section of code, you check if the `filteredIconsList` is not null. If so, set it to null. The only value which is going to equal to null is null, so skip the check and just set it to null.

```
private synchronized void filter(CharSequence s, IconsAdapter adapter) {
    if (s == null || s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        filteredIconsList = null;
        if (filteredIconsInts != null) {
            filteredIconsList = null;
        }
        ...
```

Which makes the next if statement just redundant. `filteredIconsList` is already null. So remove that if statement.

```
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

If both cases end with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, then you can just move the line to outside of the if statement.

In the else case of this if statement, you have this:

```
        if (filteredIconsInts != null) {
            filteredIconsList = null;
        }
        filteredIconsList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

That's a redundant set, you don't need to set to null if you're going to overwrite it with a new ArrayList just afterwards.

So remove the useless if-statement.

In the for loop, you retrieve the name with `iconsNames.get(i)`, but if the condition in the for loop is true, you `iconsNames.get(i)` to `filteredIconsList`. Just add `name` to the `filteredIconsList`, as you've already retrieved it.

The documentation for `toLowerCase` says this:

> `public String toLowerCase()`
>   Converts all of the characters in this `String` to lower case using the rules of the default locale. This is equivalent to calling `toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())`.

So there's no need to include the Locale. Remove the argument.

Doing all these `toLowerCase` in a loop is pretty silly, though. Move it to outside of the loop, so you only lowercase once.

Results in this:

```
private synchronized void filter(CharSequence s, IconsAdapter adapter) {
    if (s == null || s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        filteredIconsList = null;
        adapter.clearIconsList();
        adapter.setIcons(iconsNames, iconsInts);
    } else {
        if (filteredIconsList != null) {
            filteredIconsList.clear();
        }
        filteredIconsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        filteredIconsInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String lowerCaseS = s.toString.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < iconsNames.size(); i++) {
            String name = iconsNames.get(i);
            if (name.toLowerCase()
                    .startsWith(lowerCaseS)) {
                filteredIconsList.add(name);
                filteredIconsInts.add(iconsInts.get(i));
            }
        }
        adapter.clearIconsList();
        adapter.setIcons(filteredIconsList, filteredIconsInts);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If we're allowed to change the order of operations, I'd even move the `adapter.clearIconsList()` all the way to the top of the function.